# FFMPEG complex_filter_script adds long trailing blank video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I generated a complex_function_script to concatenate certain clips of an input video at different speeds.

1. When I start from the beginning of the input video, the output is
   mostly correct, but has a trailing empty video that lasts until time
   reaches that of the input.
2. When I start from the middle of the input video, ffmpeg gets stuck on frame 0.

**What causes this issue(s) and how can I fix it?** Thank you!

terminal command: (newlines added for readability)

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -i "/myfilestructure/myinputfile.mp4" \
-filter_complex_script "/myfilestructure/myoutputfile_command000.txt" \
-preset superfast "/myfilestructure/myinputfile000.mp4"
```

myoutputfile_command000.txt: (newlines added for readability)

```
[0:v]trim=0:0.032,setpts=0.6666666666666666*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v0]; \
[0:v]trim=0.032:1206.91,setpts=0.25*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v1]; \
[0:v]trim=1206.91:1206.93,setpts=0.6666666666666666*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v2]; \
[0:v]trim=1206.93:1210.5,setpts=0.25*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v3]; \
[0:v]trim=1210.5:1210.81,setpts=0.6666666666666666*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v4]; \
[0:v]trim=1210.81:1334.51,setpts=0.25*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v5]; \
[0:v]trim=1334.51:1334.53,setpts=0.6666666666666666*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v6]; \
[0:v]trim=1334.53:1477.47,setpts=0.25*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v7]; \
[0:v]trim=1477.47:1477.49,setpts=0.6666666666666666*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v8]; \
[0:v]trim=1477.49:1495.41,setpts=0.25*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v9]; \
[0:a]atrim=0:0.032,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=1.5[a0]; \
[0:a]atrim=0.032:1206.91,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=4.0[a1]; \
[0:a]atrim=1206.91:1206.93,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=1.5[a2]; \
[0:a]atrim=1206.93:1210.5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=4.0[a3]; \
[0:a]atrim=1210.5:1210.81,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=1.5[a4]; \
[0:a]atrim=1210.81:1334.51,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=4.0[a5]; \
[0:a]atrim=1334.51:1334.53,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=1.5[a6]; \
[0:a]atrim=1334.53:1477.47,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=4.0[a7]; \
[0:a]atrim=1477.47:1477.49,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=1.5[a8]; \
[0:a]atrim=1477.49:1495.41,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=4.0[a9]; \
[v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3][v4][a4][v5][a5][v6][a6][v7][a7][v8][a8][v9][a9]concat=n=10:v=1:a=1
```

all my generated scripts follow the same structure but with different times.